# What are common causes for getting {error, enoent} for file:get_cwd()?

Tags: erlang

I am using `file:get_cwd()` and I am seeing errors from it, i.e. `{error, enoent}`. What could be the underlying issue causing this error?

Comment: Don't edit my posts.  Rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the [UNIX manual page for `getcwd(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html), which is used to implement `file:get_cwd/0` on such systems, you'll find the following explanation of the `ENOENT` error result:

> ENOENT The current working directory has been unlinked.

In other words, this error occurs if the current working directory has been deleted out from under the Erlang process. A number of similar explanations of `enoent` exist in the [documentation for the `file` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html).

Try the following sequence of calls from the `erl` shell, assuming the directory `/tmp/foo` does not already exist on your system:

```
1> file:make_dir("/tmp/foo").
ok
2> cd("/tmp/foo").
/tmp/foo
ok
3> file:get_cwd().
{ok,"/tmp/foo"}
4> file:del_dir("/tmp/foo").
ok
5> file:get_cwd().
{error,enoent}
```

This sequence first creates the new directory `/tmp/foo` and changes the working directory of the `erl` process to it. The first call to `file:get_cwd()` verifies that, as expected, `/tmp/foo` is the working directory. Then the directory is removed via the call to `file:del_dir/1`. Because the working directory now no longer exists, the second call to `file:get_cwd()` returns `{error,enoent}`.